# Facts or Theorems Similar to Pigeonhole Principle

Tags: math-history, big-list, pigeonhole-principle

Are there any facts or theorems in mathematics having similar energy with pigeonhole principle? What I mean by similar energy is the statement is simple, "trivial" as you don't need to prove it to understand why it's true, but has many useful and powerful applications to prove many results. Thank you.

Comment: I hope I don`t miss the purpose of your question by posting an example that I think everyone is presented in a probability course: the birthday problem. We solved it in a seminary without even noticing we were using this principle.

Comment: @Anatol Denicula I think the birthday problem is not that obvious if I looked it at first time, but I appreciate your comment. Do you have any example how you used the birthday problem in another problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no integer (strictly) between zero and one. Looks pretty stupid, but many irrationality and transcendence proofs rely on it. [and in some sense it is equivalent to the pigeonhole principle]

Example: the proof of the transcendence of $e$ given in [http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~evertse/dio15-4.pdf](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/%7Eevertse/dio15-4.pdf) – note particularly the statement after Corollary 4.3, "Our aim is to show that for a suitable choice of $f$, the quantity $M := q_0F(0) +\cdots+ q_nF(n)$ is a non-zero integer with $|M| < 1$."

The proof of Lindemann-Weierstrass later in that same document is much more elaborate but also comes down to the non-existence of an integer $M$ with $0<M<1$.

This non-existence crops up again in the middle of the proof of the Gel'fond-Schneider Theorem, in the middle of page 64 of the same document.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, may I know some of its applications in transcendence proofs?

Comment: I'll try to get back to you with some examples. Meanwhile, https://hkumath.hku.hk/web/public/memory/ycwong-paper.pdf is a paper by William Chen with the title, There is No Integer Between 0 and 1 – A Very Brief Introduction to Geometric Discrepancy Theory. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3182681/does-all-proofs-of-irrationality-are-the-same-way-find-an-integer-between-0

Comment: thank you for your examples